# Drawing a huge graph with networkX and matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, networkx

I am drawing a graph with around 5K nodes in it using networkX and matplotlib. The GTK window by matplotlib has tools to zoom and visualise the graph. 
Is there any way, I can save a magnified version for proper visualisation later?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)   #G is my graph

nx.draw(G,pos,node_color='#A0CBE2',edge_color='#BB0000',width=2,edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,with_labels=True)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=500, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1)
```

Comment: There should be a save button also.... or at least I'm sure that one of the front-ends has that (maybe Qt's?)...

Comment: yes, there is a save button. But once you magnify a portion of the diagram and save it only saves the current viewing area. I want a view of the whole graph.

Comment: Can't you just up the `dpi` so more detail is present in the saved image?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Looks fine.  That import tends to be assumed ;)

Comment: @tcaswell I figured, I just haven't used either of these libraries much, and wanted to make sure.  By the way, networkx... wow! Anyway, I'll delete my pointless comment now.

Answer (score 34):

You have two easy options:

### Up the DPI

```
plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=1000)
```

(larger image file size)

### Save as a PDF

```
plt.savefig("graph.pdf")
```

This is the best option, as the final graph is not rasterized. In theory, you should be able to zoom in indefinitely.

Comment: @NiharSarangi I feel like the question _"save a magnified version for proper visualisation later"_ has been answered. If the image is messy and you want to customize `networkx` that might be fodder for a different question. Try turning off the labels `with_labels=True` -> `with_labels=False` in your draw command to clean it up.

Comment: Save as SVG 
plt.savefig("graph.svg") 

svg format is also not rasterized like the PDF option suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this out:

```
plt.savefig("name.svg")
```

the quality is magnificent. although the dpi option is still alive.